# How to delay method call in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, delay, synchronous, schedule

Is there a way to schedule a method call, when current processing of user input is finished? Something *like* posting an user message to the message queue.

Let's take a look on how user input is being processed:

```
1. User taps the screen                                      |  User input
2. Operating system puts a message in message queue          |  Operating system
3. WPF internals pick up the message                         \
4. WPF internals processes the message                        | WPF internals
5. WPF causes parts of application code to be run:           /
    a) As immediate reactions on events                      \  This is where call may
    b) As an effect of dependency properties being changed   /  be scheduled
6. The application code finishes                             |  Application code
7. The WPF internals finishes their work                     |  WPF internals
   *** This is where I want the scheduled method to run ***
8. WPF peeks for next message from message queue             |  WPF internals
```

How may I schedule call, such that it will happen in the place I want it to?

Comment: can you at least show what it is you currently have since you need it to be `synchronously ..? this would help to see what you are doing and or trying to do.. few questions to add, 
1. is this Multi-Threaded, 2. Can you use the `Sleep` function..? etc... please provide more information [Thread.Join Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95hbf2ta%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) good reading here if I might add

Comment: You can join() on Threads.

Comment: Look at Task Parallel Library. Not the only way but easier than traditional multi-threading and will solve your problem. Sorry, can't be more specific right now.

Comment: Would `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(...)` be the kind of thing you want?

Comment: not sure why this was voted to be closed it's very Clear in my opinion what `Spook` `moja żona jest z Polski i jestem mushin , który mówi i rozumie po polsku , jak również`.

Comment: (not close-voting) It is unclear what "processing" is. It could be anything and therefore the answer could be very different. Other than that, it's probably to broad (too many answers possible) or primarily opinion-based (some like pure Threads, others like TPL, others like P-Invoke, ...).

Comment: @Enigmativity Looks promissing. Since I'd call it from the main thread, it wouldn't run asynchronously, but synchronously, as a next "task" of the Dispatcher.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly then this is how I would solve it.

1. Declare 2 global variables:

   ```
   Action<object> gPostProcessingMethod = null;//it must be accessible to any of the methods
                          // that may decide to schedule post-processing of your message
   object gDataForPostProcessing = null;//it will hold a data for post-processing (if any)
   ```
2. I assume you have a loop somewhere that is polling your message queue. Let's assume this is `while` loop. Then it should look something like this to handle the post-processing of your messages:

   ```
       while (...)
       {
           // 1. Your code to dequeue/get next message:
           // .................................
           gPostProcessingMethod= null;
           gDataForPostProcessing = null;
           /* 2. Your code that triggers processing of the message. As far as I understand,
                 this triggering method does not return until all of the subsequently called
                 methods are done.
                 However, as you described, any of those methods may decide to schedule 
                 "post-processing" method that must start at the moment the processing is complete.
                 This is how the scheduling should be done: 
                     gPostProcessingMethod = <AnyMethodThatCompliesWithSignatureOfAction>  
                     gDataForPostProcessing = ...;
           */


           if (gPostProcessingMethod != null)
           {//You mentioned that this call MUST happen synchronously (otherwise you may use ThreadPool, etc.)
                gPostProcessingMethod(gDataForPostProcessing);
           }
           // 3. Your remaining code in the loop:
           // ......................................

       }
   ```
3. Since every subsequent processing method can overwrite values that previous ones assigned to `gPostProcessingMethod` and `gDataForPostProcessing`, you should either accept that downstream methods have priority or contrary: forbid changing these variables if they have been set already.

Comment: The loop polling message queue is embedded in WPF internals. I don't have access to it (at least none known to me).

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to make this work. My personal preference to implement this type of behavior is to use a [ConcurrentQueue<>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265(v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

You can use semaphores for multithreading,
or when singlethread just an int that gets increased on your method start and decrase on method end. You simply wait until this is back to zero.

Comment: why? I do not see a problem